# Percentage width mega menu plus standard drop down on the one html list

Tags: css

Long time reader via Google searches, first time poster.

I am trying to implement a percentage width mega menu plus a standard pixel width drop down menu on the one html list.

(I want the mega menu width to be percentage based to work in responsive layouts and I am happy with that works.)

I can't seem to get them to work together. Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eaVjT/

If I set position static on the top level li link as in example 1 in the fiddle, the mega menu works fine, but the standard drop down breaks (its not vertical).

```
#menu li { float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: static; }
```

If I set position relative on the top level li link as in example 2 in the fiddle, the standard drop down works fine (its vertical as expected), but the mega menu breaks (it gets squished to the width of the top level parent link).

```
#menu li { float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; }
```

I tried changing static and relative for the top level links by using different classes but that does not seem viable as the height of the mega menu was added to the bottom of the page.

I am totally stumped.

Any ideas?

I haven't been able to find a solution for this and hope someone can help.

Many thanks.

The full css for the #menu is as follows:

```
/*wrapper*/
#menu { width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0; text-align: left; position: relative; display: block; z-index: 6; clear: both; }

/*top level*/
#menu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#menu li { float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: static; background: #ccc; }
#menu li a { display: block; position: relative; padding: 0 10px 0 10px; }
#menu li, #menu li a { height: 50px; }
#menu li a span { line-height: 50px; }

/*std drop down*/
#menu li ul { margin: 0; left: -999em; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 20; }
#menu li:hover ul { left: 0; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; overflow: visible; }
#menu li li { float: left; width: 200px; position: relative; display: block; background: #999; }
#menu li li, #menu li li a { height: auto; }
#menu li li a { display: block; padding: 8px 10px; }

/*mega drop down*/
#menu li .drop { width: 100%; left: -999em; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 20; background: #333; }
#menu li:hover .drop { left: 0; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; overflow: visible; }
#menu li .drop ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; }
#menu li .drop li { float: none; width: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative; background: #666; }
#menu li .drop p a, #menu li .drop li a { position: relative; display: block; }
/*columns*/
#menu .drop .col { width: 23%; height: auto; margin: 15px 1.5% 0 0; float: left; display: block; position: relative; }
#menu .drop .col.first { margin-left: 1.5%; }
#menu .drop .col.last { width: 23.5%; margin-right: 0; }
/*links*/
#menu .drop p { padding: 0; }
#menu .drop p a { padding: 5px 0 8px 0; }
#menu .drop li a, #menu .drop li.last a { padding: 5px 0; }

/*text*/
#menu li a span, #menu li li a, #menu .drop p a, #menu .drop li a { color: #fff; font-size: 1.5em; text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of would be to change the mega dropdown's `position` to `fixed`. In doing so, it is no longer absolutely positioned relative to the parent's confined width.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2raqL/)

```
#menu li .drop {
    width: 100%;
    left: -999em;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;   /* Changed.. */
    z-index: 20;
    background: #333;
}
```

If the above solution is problematic, an alternative would be to remove the `left` positioning and then remove the floats from the nested `li` elements. In doing so, you don't have to relatively position the parent `ul` elements.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6kjET/)

Remove the following:

```css
#menu li .drop { left: -999em; }

#menu li:hover ul { left: 0; }
```

Add the following:

```css
#menu > ul > li > ul > li { float: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! That is amazing. I had absolutely no idea what the solution would be. You are a genius. The first is very elegant and so simple in changing just the one thing. The second is also excellent and works equally as well. I recreated the menu demos this end using your adjustments and some updated css and did some browser testing - both solutions tested well, even back to IE7. So am I unsure which solution to actually use. I also have limited experience using items as position: fixed. In your experience, would you go with solution 1 or 2? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: By clicking the tick to make it green, have I marked your response as the solution?

Comment: @user3643520 Yep, you accepted it as the solution. Glad to hear that they both worked. Even though it may be considered a bit of a hack to some, i'd probably go with the first option for simplicity. It's up to you though; the first one might work better if you ever need to add a third-level dropdown because the `ul` maintains the relative positioning - I don't think you would have that flexibility using the second option.

Comment: Thankyou Josh. Agreed, I will run with the first option as there is less to change. Just so you know, I added a third-level to the standard drop down to test and it worked fine with both options so that doesn't make the choice any easier - both your solutions were too good and flexible! Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I did run into trouble with the first solution (position: fixed for the mega menu). In my initial testing I didn't include any columns, page wrappers etc and when I tested with those the mega menu was still filling the full window which was not what I was after. So I went with the second solution and it is working a treat with the page wrappers. Thanks again.